# How can I uninstall a cracked version of Deep Freeze Standard?

Tags: windows, uninstall, deep-freeze

My laptop was broken so we went to a repair shop and got it fixed (not actually fixed) and the repair guy installed Deep Freeze Standard (Version: 7.22.020.3453) that is cracked (not original).

Before you go saying "Just find the installer that you used to install it" Blah Blah like that, It's gone...

I downloaded the installer from [their official site](http://www.faronics.com).
But when I launched the installer, It says "This install program cannot determine product version information".

How can I uninstall this cracked version of Deep Freeze Standard?

Answer (score -2):

You do need the installer used to install the program. The software must also be in the "thawed" state for uninstall to work.

Find the installer file "DFStd.exe". From that directory, run the command:

```
DFStd.exe /Uninstall
```

Comment: The original poster posted this issue nearly a year ago. I doubt they will be able to use this information.